# localStorage not working to save a dynamic CSS backgroundColor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to persist an array item that refers to a button color on my HTML but it's not working.

My HTML:

```html
<div class="buttons">
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

let i = 0;

for (const button of buttons) {
  button.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let colors = ["red", "yellow", "green"];
    localStorage.setItem("currentColor", colors[i++ % colors.length]);
    button.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.getItem("currentColor");
    i++;
  });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Also, you are incrementing `i` twice.

Comment: It's not saving to localStorage, when I refresh the page the colors did not persist.

Comment: Well of course they don't persist, you always do `setItem` as the very first thing...

Comment: Are you trying to remember an actual color, which on reload will not help much as It will be reset. Did you mean to save i?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep/save it when the page is refreshed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always doing `localStorage.setItem()` in your function, which overwrites whatever value was saved. Instead, you should first check if the value is already in `localStorage`, and if so retrieve it.

Secondly, just saving the color won't work alone. You will need to save the index of the color if you want to be able to "resume" the cycle of colors. Alternatively, save the color and then locate its index when restoring it from `localStorage`.

Here's a working solution:

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
let i = 0;

for (const button of buttons) {
  button.style.backgroundColor = "white";

  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let colors = ["red", "yellow", "green"];

    const saved = localStorage.getItem('colorIndex');
    if (saved !== null)
        i = parseInt(saved);
    
    button.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];

    if (++i == colors.length)
        i = 0;

    localStorage.setItem('colorIndex', i);
  });
}
```

Note that this will restore the previous color only after you click on a button, if you want to restore it immediately just move the `colors` and the `localstorage.getItem()` outside the click listener.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime the `for` loop loops, it will overwrite the previous data in `localStorage`, so everytime you will only have 1 color in `localStorage`.

A much simpler solution is to store it in an array and let `localStorage` store the array which is much easier especially when you have data need to be updated.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

let i = 0;
let storecolor = []
for (const button of buttons) {
  button.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let colors = ["red", "yellow", "green"];
    storecolor.push(colors[i++ % colors.length])
    localStorage.setItem("currentColor", JSON.stringify(storecolor));
    button.style.backgroundColor = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentColor"));
    i++;
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
          <button></button>
</div>
```